# Checking the internet connection in android is either through Wifi or through GSM/3G?

Tags: android, connectivity

How can I check using code whether the connection made is through Wifi or GSM/3G in android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From here: [Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android/2945774#2945774)

```
// Only update if WiFi or 3G is connected and not roaming
int netType = info.getType();
int netSubtype = info.getSubtype();

if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
    return info.isConnected();
 } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
        && netSubtype == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
        && !mTelephony.isNetworkRoaming()) {
     return info.isConnected();
 } else {
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you can use TelephonyManager.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String operatorname = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html