# how I can know if a tablet has 3G connection

Tags: android

The question.
I'm getting error on this line:

```
android.net.NetworkInfo.State mobile = con.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
```

The error you are giving Tablets that have no 3G connection can only connect through WI-FI.
Is there a way to ask if the device lacks 3G connection?

Comment: why not first check if the tablet supports mobile as well as wi-fi, and then check for network type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(NetworkInfo.getType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

    // .getState() here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this list of SO Q&A:

- [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)
- [Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)
- [Is there a way to detect 2G, 3G, or 4G on Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735100/is-there-a-way-to-detect-2g-3g-or-4g-on-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are happy to find out whether the tablet has a cellular radio or not, how about:

```
@Override
public boolean hasCellularRadio() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    if (deviceId == null || deviceId.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```