# Android DownloadManager over 2G\3G

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I noticed the Android DownloadManager Request can be set to download over NETWORK_MOBILE \ NETWORK_WIFI
but is it possible to distinguish between 2G \ 3G \ LTE?

thanks.

Comment: maybe the follow link is what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735100/is-there-a-way-to-detect-2g-3g-or-4g-on-android-device

Comment: May not be a duplicate, the other question is asking how to tell if the device has capability, I think this wants to find out what is being used for a stream?

Comment: I was asking if the downloadManager has this compatibility build in, but I think by your answer I can undersand DM doesn't, so I can check with your suggestion and then by it to create my request.