# How to monitor network type and get notified if it changes

Tags: android, 3g, android-networking, telephonymanager

I'm trying to make an app to both show the state of the network type (2G, 3G, or 4G), which I have done by using TelephonyManager, and also notify the user whenever the network type changes. 
This is the part I have problem in, how can I monitor the network type and get notified whenever it changes?

Comment: Have you tried `listen` method in TelephonyManager?

Comment: I can not understand this method in the [Google Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener, int))  can you break it down for me a little bit, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while here is a working code:

under `onCreate` :

```
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
```

and as a class :

```
public class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {  
    public void onDataConnectionStateChanged (int state, int networkType){
        super.onDataConnectionStateChanged(state, networkType);  
   //Whatever you wanna do  
      }  
}
```

the method `onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType)` gets triggered when either networkstype(2G,3G,4G) changes or the connection state (Connecting, disconnecting etc) changes

Answer (score 1):

You should find your answer here for network changes http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

EDIT for mobile networks check out this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/21721139/1898809

And this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341777/1898809

Comment: Thanks, though this shows whether its mobile data or wifi or wimax ... what I need is to monitor different types of mobile data (2G, 3G, or 4G) any idea on that ?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, two links in the edited part determines the types of mobile data, when called, what I want though is to get notified when it changed. 
let me make an example; say the user is traveling by car, and between cities or in the deserts you do not always have a 3G or 4G coverage, and user wants to be notified as soon as a 3 or 4G network is available.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this: (Remember this will only work on Android 4.2+)

```
    // It Only works on Android 4.2+
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfo) {
            super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo);
            for (CellInfo ci : cellInfo) {
                if (ci instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "This has 2G");
                } else if (ci instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "This has 4G");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "This has 3G");
                }
            }
        }


    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO);
```

You will also need the `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time buddy, I keep getting >Unfortunately, APP has stopped< Error and here is the red parts of Logcat
>
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at test.e_rundev.ir.test2.MyActivity$3.onCellInfoChanged(MyActivity.java:92)
            at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)<

Comment: >
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
<


I also added the permissions, the one you mentioned and >android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION< as Android Studio asked me to ... any Idea ?

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException in `onCellInfoChanged` method which I think is because cellInfo is null. Try adding an if statement to check for nullity of cellInfo and see if that solves your problem. Btw do you run it on a device or a simulator?

Comment: I'm running it on my Note 3 device, which currently has a 2G - Edge coverage
Using getNetworkType method of TelephonyManager I can get "NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE"

Comment: I can take my device for a ride in car in couple of hours, will let you know then. but with the if statement for nullity of cellInfo it seems that the app should work.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work! 
is there any way we can set the listen for NetworkType which can be reached with getNetworkType method of the TelephonyManager?

Comment: You could replace 'PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO' with 'PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO| onDataConnectionStateChanged.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE` and the override 'onDataConnectionStateChanged' in `PhoneStateListener`