# In android is there any event trigger, when network type change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, connectivity

In Android there is a availability of different types of network that is 3g,EDGE,LTE etc. i am searching  for the event when user network type change from EDGE to 3g,LTE and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) that will get called whenever network state changes(connection lost,changed,etc). In the receiver class you would have to figure out the kind of network network you are intrested in. The [connectivity manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class will help you figure out the type of connected network.

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

**Update**:

You can use [TelephonyManager.getNetworkType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735100/is-there-a-way-to-detect-2g-3g-or-4g-on-android-device) but I am not aware of any broadcast receiver that can be registered to be notified about the change in the network.

Comment: it work only when network connectivity switch between mobile network and wifi but it does not work when mobile network change from 2G to 3G and 4G etc.