# Can I use both internet connections on a phone simultaneously in Android Programming?

Tags: android, apn

If I've a Dual-SIM phone (3G and 2G respectively), and I want to connect to both the internet networks simultaneously, is it possible through Android Development ?

To repeat, I want both connections to be active and simultaneously maintained.

Comment: Nope, its not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735100/is-there-a-way-to-detect-2g-3g-or-4g-on-android-device & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g follow this two link.