# Which Intent is broadcasted when networkType(Telephony Manager) changes

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want my app to automatically notify the user when the networkType changes(eg from EDGE to 3G or 3G to 1XRTT etc). Using the getNetworkType() method, I have to continuously check for a change in networkType. Is there some kind of intent being broadcasted throughout the system when a change is detected. I am curently using

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();  
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
```

but it only detects for change from network connectivity change not for networkType. Is there any other intent or listener which detects networkType chaange.

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the connection using Telephony manager inside broadcast receiver. This link may help you. [connection change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g)

Answer (score 0):

maybe ACTION_ANY_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED Broadcast Action is what you want.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(TelephonyIntents.ACTION_ANY_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(TelephonyIntents.ACTION_DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED);
filter.addAction(DataConnectionTracker.ACTION_DATA_CONNECTION_TRACKER_MESSENGER);
```