# How can i identify that the data connection used by the android phone is 2.75G, 3G or 4G?

Tags: java, android, 3g, 4g

How can I identify programmatically whether the data connection used by the android phone is 2.75G, 3G or 4G?

I am requiring this, for gathering data from multiple users using different data connections for data services.

Comment: hi you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17341777/1140237

Answer (score 1):

Use TelephonyManager.GetNetworkType().  The network types correspond to your requirements as follows:

**GSM-based systems:**

NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS    Current network is GPRS - 2G
NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE    Current network is EDGE - sometimes called 2.75G
NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS    Current network is UMTS - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA   Current network is HSDPA - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA   Current network is HSUPA - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA    Current network is HSPA - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP   Current network is HSPA+ - 3G, but sometimes called 3.5G
NETWORK_TYPE_LTE     Current network is LTE - 4G

NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN    Current network is iDen - [a Motorola system built on GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEN) - corresponds to 2G

**CDMA-based systems:**

NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA    Current network is CDMA: Either IS95A or IS95B - 2G
NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT   Current network is 1xRTT - Sometimes called 2.5G.
NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD   Current network is eHRPD - the best explanation I found for eHRPD is [here](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28732334-eHRPD-Information).  Basically, it's an evolution of EVDO, that is routed through the LTE core, so that EVDO can hand over seamlessly to LTE.  LTE is Qualcomm's 4G system of choice for CDMA handsets (see [here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) under "UMB"). eHRPD is 3G.
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0  Current network is EVDO revision 0 - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A  Current network is EVDO revision A - 3G
NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B  Current network is EVDO revision B - 3G

There is a comparison of mobile network standards, including some figures about maximum speeds, that put the 2G/3G/4G estimates into context, on [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wireless_data_standards)  Check out the speeds of HSPA+ and LTE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of [TelephonyManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g/17341777#17341777) sample code.

Check out this answer [How to determine if network type is 2G, 3G or 4G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g/17341777#17341777)

Comment: Sure Let me Edit the answer.

Comment: np man .. bt i guess nw ur answer should b comment... anyways np cheers

Comment: I was new hear i don't have enough rep to comment at that time. so I don't no how things work. so no Hard feelings man!