# Search for 4G Network

Tags: android, telephonymanager, lte, 4g

How to programmatically (for Android) search for 4G network and get the result ?

To be more clear : When I clicked a button it search for all available 4G network and show me the result in a list.

**Edit:**

I need a result by code and something like this :
[This is while you search for network on your mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx11G.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here -- > <sub>**[How to determine if network type is 2G, 3G or 4G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g)**</sub>

`getNetworkType()` will return you the `NETWORK_TYPE_xxxx` for current data connection, I picked this method among the answers for my work, add whatever the network types you want to filter among these switch cases

You can put this following method directly in your Utility class:

```
    public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Read the document its clean & clear -> <sub>**https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType()**</sub>

**Edit**

If you want to do a scan
you need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for Wifi scan results:and filter with `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE`

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            // add your logic here to filter
        }
    }
}
```

In `onCreate()` you would assign `mWifiManager` and initiate a scan:

```
mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
mWifiManager.startScan();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but this is not my query , the point is **device is not connected** and I want to check that the device is support which 4G network .

Comment: For that do you need an app? Its there on the device spec

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but your response is for searching for Wifi not for 4G LTE !

Comment: @Saeed Sazani without searching for wireless networks and filtering what you need what is your approach to find networks then ???

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }


Also, I would first check if connected network is WiFi or Mobile.   

     public static boolean getActiveNetworkType(Context context) {
            boolean is_wfi_conected = false;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null  && activeNetwork.isConnected() && activeNetwork.isAvailable()) { // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    // connected to Wifi
                    //GET IP Address of connected WIFI
                  //  WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    is_wfi_conected = true;


                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    is_wfi_conected = false;
                }
            } else {
                // not connected to the internet
            }
            return is_wfi_conected;
        }
```