# How detect networktype (2G/3G/LTE) when connected to WiFi

Tags: android

I'm currently writing an app where I want to detect which network type (2G, 3G or LTE) an Android device is currently connected to. I have tried using the following solutions:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
tm.getNetworkType()
```

and Connectivitymanager:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getSubtype()
```

Both methods work fine without WiFi connection but if connected to a WiFI TelephonyManager returns https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN and ConnectivityManager returns 0 (UNKNOWN).

Is there any way to find out if a phone is connected to 2G, 3G or LTE even if it is connected to a WiFi network?

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283765/how-to-determine-if-network-type-is-2g-3g-or-4g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that in API-version 24 and forward getNetworkType() has been split in into two separate methods:

[getDataNetworkType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDataNetworkType())

and

[getVoiceNetworkType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getVoiceNetworkType())

I added a check in my code to se if the returned type was IWLAN and if so use getVoiceNetworkType() instead.

```
if (tm.getNetworkType() != 18)
    return tm.getNetworkType();
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    return tm.getVoiceNetworkType();
else 
    return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `getAllNetworks()` from `ConnectivityManager` which tracks all active networks.

See here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getAllNetworks()

You can retrieve more detailed information on a certain returned network with `getNetworkInfo()`

See here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately getAllNetworks() only returns one Network instance which is of type WIFI even though I'm also connected to the mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

**call this method**

```
public void checkNetworkType(){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA)) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "3G network type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "4G network type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPRS network type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "2G network type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work as getNetworkType returns TYPE_IWLAN if I am connected on a WIFI at the time.