# We need PhoneStateListener or Broadcast Receiver or both?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I'm new to Android programming and have the following doubt.

To detect a change (for example change in signal strength) and show the message (i.e Toast message) in the precise moment of any change, do I need to use both, a `PhoneStateListener` and a `BroadcastReceiver` or only one of them? Which one?

The target is Android 6(API 23)

Thanks for any help. Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the case of signal strength, you should use the former; the latter is simply used to listen to any system changes. The former is limited to Telephony states. Since you haven't provided sufficient information on your app and what problem you are trying to solve, it's hard to give full answer that can help.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've actually asked and look for a solution before to get my goal. I'm trying for Android 6 (Api 23) to detect when the phone changes between network types (2G/GSM, 3G/WCDMA, 4G/LTE). I was able to detect changes from no connection, WiFi, Mobile but not between mobile technologies. I've asked here that https://stackoverflow.com/q/57602868/5691558