# Galaxy Nexus issue - 4G support detection

Tags: android, 4g

4G device detection code what i use is working in all other devices except Samsung Galaxy Nexus(toro)

This is the code what i use

```
boolean is4G = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.verizon.hardware.telephony.lte");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your app only for verizon?

I think they have changed the feature name in toro

https://bitbucket.org/kejar31/android_vendor_samsung/src/956695341253/toro/proprietary/com.vzw.hardware.lte.xml

Try this code.. It may work

```
hasSystemFeature("com.vzw.hardware.lte");
```

Comment: Yes.. only for verizon devices

Answer (score 2):

4G is actually a marketing term, not a technical term.  It generally means that the phone has an LTE, WiMAX, or HSPA connection.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android) question for details on determining the current connection type on Android.

Comment: I saw this link.. It is for finding current connected network. A 4G device can be connected to 3G network also. I have to find out the device is 4G capable device or not