# Android: How to Know an IP Address is a Wifi IP Address?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I want to know the whether IP address of an Android device is Data IP or Wifi IP.

1) Device as is connected to 3G first, now the Device will be assigned to Network IP.

2) Later Device connected to WIFI , now the Device will be assigned to WIFI IP.

3)Any Android API which will let us know an IP Address is a Wifi IP Address or Network IP??

Was Using below in 2.3.5 and things were fine, but in 4.0.3 ICS has some issues..

```
   /**
 * Is the IP Address a a Wifi Ip Address.
 * @param ipAddr
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isWifiIp(byte[] ipAddr){
    try{
        WifiManager mgr = (WifiManager)mCxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int wifiIP = mgr.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
        int reverseWifiIP = Integer.reverseBytes(wifiIP);  
        int byteArrayToInt = byteArrayToInt(ipAddr,0);

        if(byteArrayToInt == wifiIP || byteArrayToInt == reverseWifiIP)
            return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.d(TAG, e);
    }
    return false;
}


/**
 * Convert IP Address in bytes to int value.
 * @param arr
 * @param offset
 * @return int
 */
public static final int byteArrayToInt(byte[] arr, int offset) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length - offset < 4)
        return -1;

    int r0 = (arr[offset] & 0xFF) << 24;
    int r1 = (arr[offset + 1] & 0xFF) << 16;
    int r2 = (arr[offset + 2] & 0xFF) << 8;
    int r3 = arr[offset + 3] & 0xFF;
    return r0 + r1 + r2 + r3;
}

/**
 *  Fetches the IP Address of the Client. There is Delay of 2 Seconds for the API to return.
 */
public String getClientIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if(isWifiIp(inetAddress.getAddress())){
                    Logger.d(TAG, "-------- Local IP Address; Not Valid: "+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                    continue;
                }
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                    Logger.d(TAG, "-------- Some Valid IPv4 is ---"+ipAddress);
                    return ipAddress;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Pls Help

4) When i turn off Mobile Data Network and Wifi Is On,I still get a Some Valid IPv4 Address, which is not seen in 2.3.5 and Below.

Thanks

Comment: The question is just wrong on so many levels...

Comment: What is wrong be more precise and make it correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the trick..
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getName()

getName for WiFi will start with wlan..using this validate WiFi IP.

Comment: You are different bro. For upvoting your answer I logged in again.

Answer (score 4):

You cant detect connection type based on IP address because your mobile network and home WiFi network, both can assign private IP address.

What you need to do is to first detect either you have mobile network or WiFi connection, and then based on that info get the IP address of that connection.

Comment: Just to complement this answer, take a look at this question about detecting the type of network connectivity on Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Comment: did you read Guido García's suggested link. it got good instructions to detect several different types of networks

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blundell.tut.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        checkAvailableConnection();
    }

    void checkAvailableConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable()) {

            WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            int ipAddress = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress();
            System.out.println("WiFi address is "
                    + android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddress));

        } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {

            GetLocalIpAddress();
            Toast.makeText(this, "3G Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private String GetLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                        .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            return "ERROR Obtaining IP";
        }
        return "No IP Available";
    }
}
```