# Router Id address giving an error?

Tags: android, ip, wifi

I want to find out the ip address of the router with i am connect, but my program gives me Zero(0) ip address why i am getting 0 ip address as my WIFI is already working, i am running this code on  EMULATOR.

my code is:

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    String ipString = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",(ip & 0xff),(ip >> 8 & 0xff),(ip >> 16 & 0xff),(ip >> 24 & 0xff));
```

Comment: First of all check where is null value with debugger or simple sysouts. I also think that wifiInfo can be null when wifi is turned off and it hasn't been started since device turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out the IP Address of your phone which is connected to any Network or hotspot, you can use the code from this link

[android: get IP over WIFI on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835017/android-get-ip-over-wifi-on-ics?lq=1)