# Android: Send data only by WIFI

Tags: android, service, wifi

I have a service that runs in background and send data to a server, I want to send this data only by wifi and not another way (gprs or else) is that possible? and if it is, how can I achieve that? if you have sample codes or links that would be great.
thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
 this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
 connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

The NetworkInfo structure should have the connectivity state of the Wifi Subsystem. Look at the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

Use the `isConnected` method to see if wifi is connected. Easy Peasy!

Comment: networkinfo is deprecated then how we use this in above api 24

Answer (score 1):

[Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

This post might be what you're looking for, you can check to see if your app is connected to wifi before sending any data. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

try looking at this:
http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/connectivity_patterns.html#WiFi
i think you'll find your answer there