# How do I force Android to use wifi network instead of mobile network

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a use case where I need to use Wifi network for my requests instead of the mobile network. The mobile device has already connected to the Wifi network. But Android seems to always resolve network requests using the mobile data network instead of the Wifi network. Note that the Wifi network does not have internet access, it is simply a wifi access point exposed by an external device during setup.

I tried using ConnectivityManager's setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) but that did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Send data only by WIFI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742894/android-send-data-only-by-wifi)

Comment: No it does not look like a duplicate. The answer to that question refers to checking the isConnected state which does not solve this problem where the wifi already connected, but not getting used.

Comment: So why it doesn't solve the problem then? isConnected will be `true` when the wifi is connected and `false` when it's not.

Comment: Even when it is connected to Wifi, when we try to make network request from the webview, it resolves those network requests using mobile data instead of Wifi. Thats the problem.

Comment: Might need to see a bit of that code.

Comment: You can block some specific urls from loading on 3G/4G by overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in your `WebViewClient`. You can check whether the connection is over wifi for a specific url. This is just a guess, haven't tried it on practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Lollipop defaults to Mobile Data when Wi-Fi has not Internet access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164298/android-lollipop-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-not-internet-access)

Comment: This is how you do it (please upvote the answer if it solves your problem):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70977088/2267817

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Disable mobile data while wifi setup is required.</strike>
<strike>It won't resolve any requests with a carrier network if this is enabled.</strike>

Enable aeroplane mode, then toggle wifi

Comment: As long as you are not trying to solve the access problem from within the code of an app, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Enable aeroplane mode, then toggle wifi