# Detecting 3G or Wifi and redirect to a specific site

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g

I am new over here and new with Android. Ive did some research related to integrate Android API in a existing website. Because I want to detect on a existing website if the visitors has 3G or Wifi enable. I came out to this website '[Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)'. But I dont know or you just can past Android API into php files or do you need to create a android application for this function.

---

Is t even possible to detect 3g or wifi on a web based website?