# Android multiple webservice call for a single activity

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

For a single screen, I have to show data which is not available from a single webservice call. I have to call three independent different webservices to get all the data to show in the screen. If I call three at a time, there is chance of getting false in poor connection and if I call one by one, then it will take long time and give poor experience to user. How to deal with this problem so that it gives best user experience and lowest chance of failure in internet connection.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post would be off on [UX Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Anyway, if your asking for something technical though, what we used before is implement a connection speed utility class (ConnectivityUtil) and provides a method `hasFastConnection`. See sample implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android).

So when it detects a slow connection, we show a `Toast` saying something like "Your connection is a little bit wonky!" or any other. This would switch the blame to the user's connection rather than your app being slow.

We also increased our timeouts for this and if you have access to the backend, enable GZip compression and handle it appropriately on the client.