# Determining if Network Type is 2G,3G or 4G

Tags: java, android, android-networking, connectivity

i am developing an android application where in i am checking the type of mobile data network for 2G,3G and 4G. I am using the below code for it.

```
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        int netType = info.getType();
        int netSubType = info.getSubtype();
```

I am checking the 2G Connectivity using the Below code.

```
        if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE)
        {
            Log.e("2G enabled","2G enabled");
        }
```

And using the Below code for checking 3G connectivity.

```
        else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA)
        {
            Log.e("3G enabled","3G enabled");   
        }
```

How ever the above code for 3G is not working. And I tried using the below code too.

```
     TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA

     TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA

     TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
```

Still its unable to detect 3G availability. Not Getting where I am going wrong! Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like below:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);      


if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA)) {
        Log.d("3G enabled", "3G enabled");
    } else if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP)) {
        Log.d("4G enabled", "4G enabled"); 
    }else if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE)) {
        Log.e("2G enabled","2G enabled");
    }
```

Comment: can u help me, how to use this code in dual sim enable mobile ?