# How to differentiate whether internet is wifi or mobile data in android?

Tags: android

actually i need to implement a code for whether wifi internet available or not in my android mobile. i have a code, in this is internet connection available or not.please help me. Thanks

Comment: Duplcate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Comment: @Nand, your code is exactly the same as Squonk's code from :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);


  final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if( wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {   
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

use these permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

[ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) Class that answers queries about the state of network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context) {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I got after some research.

This is for getting the Wifi State:

```
public static boolean getWifiState(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        return mWifi.isConnected();

    }
```

This is for getting the gprs :

```
public static boolean getNetworkType(Context context) {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            int type = tm.getNetworkType();
            //Here you can actually get some info on the network type. Try it out. 
            if (type >= TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Last thing is to add permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK" />
```

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
public static boolean isDataEnabled(Context context)
{
    return (isMobileDataEnabled(context) || isWifiEnabled(context));
}


public static boolean isMobileDataEnabled(Context context)
{
    if(context == null)
        return false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }
    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
}

public static boolean isWifiEnabled(Context context)
{
    if(context == null)
        return false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```