# NetworkInfo Subtype values

Tags: android

If I start the application over Wi-Fi and I switch to 3G, it prints **0, 15**, so it's mobile network but I don't know why that subtype means. Then I switch back to Wi-Fi and it prints **0, 3** for a second (Mobile network, NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS) and displays that I'm connected to a mobile network on my UI, finaly it connects to Wi-Fi and it prints **1, 0**. So what does 15 means? Docs doesn't say what are these values.

```
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    int netType = networkInfo.getType();
    int netSubtype = networkInfo.getSubtype();

    Log.d("Receiver", String.valueOf(netType));
    Log.d("Receiver", String.valueOf(netSubtype));

    if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        Log.i("Receiver", "WiFi");
    } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
            && netSubtype == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
            && !telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()) {
        Log.i("Receiver", "Mobile");
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getSubtype()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an accompanying method called `getSubtypeName()` which will return a human-readable value describing the subtype.

EDIT: Digging through the source, it seems that it will be one of the `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_*` constants (e.g. `NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS`)

Comment: Damn thank you! I found that opening my own link it goes to that function, so clueless!

Answer (score 5):

```
So what does 15 means?
```

It means how fast your internet connection through the mobile connection is, so constant 15 is actually `HSPA+`

```
HSPA+ (also called Evolved HSPA or 4G) is a further evolution of 
HSPA that offers data speeds of up to 42 Mbps.
```

you can go to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

sample code:

```
if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return true;
    }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        switch(subType){
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            return false; // ~ 100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
        /*
         * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
         * to appropriate level to use these
         */
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
            return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
            return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
            return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
            return false; // ~25 kbps 
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
            return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
        // Unknown
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return false;
        }
```

Have a look at the `NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP` it has a connection speed of `10-20 Mbps`

Comment: That's strange then... When I successfully connect to the mobile network it is NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS, but while switching to Wi-Fi it changes to HSPA+. Thanks for the speed values!