# Find operators networks in Android

Tags: android, network-programming

If my question is not declared, please try to correct it.

My question is: there is any code find 2g, 3g, and lte (operators) networks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect network connection type on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

At the app level, afaik, you can't search for a list of available operators. At most you can find out if device is connected or not and the class of connection. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

At the operating system level, again afaik, you can't tap into or modify existing behaviour of stock Android. You would have to root the device and communicate with the relevant device driver that manages this.