# How to check Internet connection in services and as soon as internet is up services should start running

Tags: android, android-service

Im my app I am writing one service which runs in the background and after every hour it updates the local db in devices as soon as new updates are received and i am sending the status bar notification to the user.

In my services i am making a rest api call but i need to check that if internet connection is down the service for making api calls should not run. I know how to make it in activity but don't know how to do it in the services.

**SchedulingService.java**

```
public class SchedulingService extends IntentService {
 DbHandler DbHandler;
 List<Shipment> _shipmentList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        checkNotificationStatus();
        // Waking up the Alarm Manager after some time
        TrackerAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

 public void checkNotificationStatus() {
        List<String> notificationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<User, String> notificationMap = new HashMap<User, String>();
        UserTracker userTracker;

        UserService apiService;
        DbHandler = new DbHandler(this);
        _userList = DbHandler.getAllActiveUsers();
        // Here i am making the API call
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ApiMessage.API_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(UserService.class);

     sendNotification(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To Check the availability of the internet in the Android application, use the following approach by calling the `isInternetAvailable()` method:

```
/*
 * Checks if WiFi or 3G is enabled or not. server
 */
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    return isWiFiAvailable(context) || isMobileDateAvailable(context);
}

/**
 * Checks if the WiFi is enabled on user's device
 */
public static boolean isWiFiAvailable(Context context) {
    // ConnectivityManager is used to check available wifi network.
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo network_info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // Wifi network is available.
    return network_info != null
            && network_info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
}

 /**
 * Checks if the mobile data is enabled on user's device
 */
public static boolean isMobileDateAvailable(Context context) {
    // ConnectivityManager is used to check available 3G network.
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // 3G network is available.
    return networkInfo != null
            && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <!-- For checking the network state -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Recommendation**
This approach checks for the connectivity of the Wifi and the Mobile data using the OS. **BUT** is it not reliable because sometimes the user will be connected to one of those without having a permission to access the internet like what happened in most of the Cafes and Hotel until you login using `username` and password`

That's why I recommend you to create a simple HTML file into you server and `PING` it with checking the return content. If the content matches each other then you are having a reliable internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

[Detect network connection type on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

to check that if internet connection

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();}
```

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You can use the ConnectivityManager to check that you're actually connected to the Internet, and if so, what type of connection is in place.

[Monitor for Changes in Connectivity](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    switch (tm.getNetworkType()) {
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        Log.d("Type", "3g");
        // for 3g HSDPA networktype will be return as
        // per testing(real) in device with 3g enable
        // data
        // and speed will also matters to decide 3g network type
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
        Log.d("Type", "4g");
        // No specification for the 4g but from wiki
        // i found(HSPAP used in 4g)
        // http://goo.gl/bhtVT
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        Log.d("Type", "GPRS");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        Log.d("Type", "EDGE 2g");
        break;
    // case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
    // break;
    // case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
    // break;
    // case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
    // break;
    // case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
    // break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the internet connection using the following method:

```
/**
 * This method checks if the device has an active internet 
 * connection or not.
 * 
 * @param context
 *          - context of the class from where it is called
 * @return
 *      Returns true if there is internet connectivity
 */
public static Boolean checkInternet(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return true;
    }
    else if (netInfo != null && (netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for starting your process/services as soon as you get an active internet connection use a Braodcast receiver:

```
public class ConnectionReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

Context context;
public String TAG = "ConnectionReciever";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;
    //read internet connectivity state
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {   
        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra
                (ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        //connected to Internet
        if (currentNetworkInfo != null && currentNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
             // start sync process
        } 
        else if (currentNetworkInfo != null && (currentNetworkInfo.getState() ==
                NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED || currentNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING 
                || currentNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED || 
                currentNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN)) {

            // when Internet is disconnected
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Its been very easy by using [**this Library**](http://compile%20'com.treebo:internetavailabilitychecker:1.0.1').
>   For detail [**check here**](https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/check-active-internet-connection-on-android-device-3138ad81932d).

**Demo Code:**

```
public class MultiPostUploader extends Service implements InternetConnectivityListener {

        private Context mContext;
        private InternetAvailabilityChecker mInternetAvailabilityChecker;
        private boolean isConnected = true;

        public MultiPostUploader() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mContext = this;
            InternetAvailabilityChecker.init(this);
            mInternetAvailabilityChecker = InternetAvailabilityChecker.getInstance();
            mInternetAvailabilityChecker.addInternetConnectivityListener(this);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }


        @Override
        public void onInternetConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected) {
            // If true you have perform your action;
            this.isConnected = isConnected;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mInternetAvailabilityChecker
                    .removeInternetConnectivityChangeListener(this);
        }
    }
```