# detect slow internet connection in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed Android application and it is working fine when it using WiFi.
It also works when there is proper cellular network.
But the problem is when the signal is weak (still active connection) then there is a problem.

I have used a loader till the data is being loaded on Activity.
Now how to determine the slow internet connection because i have to give some toast information to the user that internet connectivity is slow.
Can anyone help on this.?

Comment: May be tracking down data per second

Comment: I dint get you.?Can you provide some code snippet for the same?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class if it helps

Comment: here a way to find different connection types in android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total amount data transferred from you app using `TrafficStats` of `android.net` package. Then you detect amount of data transferred per second which gives the speed of you network link

```
    trafficStats = new TrafficStats();
    uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
    if(trafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid) != trafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
        initialBytesCount = trafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid) / 1024;
    } else{
        uid = -1;
    }

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            linkSpeed = trafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid) / 1024 - initialBytesCount;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    transferRate = 0;
                    long recordedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
                    try {
                        transferRate = linkSpeed / recordedTime;
                        Log.i("TransferRate", transferRate + "");
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    netWorkSpeedTimer = new Timer();
    netWorkSpeedTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply arjun...but how to use this i.e what parameter i use from this code to determine slow internet connectivity.I am using http request response so what is the relation?

Comment: `transferRate` gives speed of link in  kbps, from which you can determine slow connectivity

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a stable connection and you just want to test if the connection is to slow for your purpose, you could implement a simple speedtest **by downloading a test file from your server and stop the taken time**. So you could set a maximum amount of time your file needs to download and if this maximum is exceeded the connection of your client is too slow.