# android how to check wifi is connected but no internet connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

android my device connected with wifi but how to if wifi is connected but these is no internet connection

following is my code that i trying to check if no internet connection

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info=null;
        if(context!=null){
            info= IsNetConnectionAvailable.getNetworkInfo(context);
        }
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
```

it always return true when no internet access

Comment: Hey, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 17):

`NetworInfo.isAvailable` and `NetworkInfo.isConnected` only indicate whether network connectivity is possible or existed, they can't indicate whether the connected situation has access to the public internet, long story short, they can't tell us the device is online indeed.

To check whether a device is online, try the following methods:

**First:**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public static boolean isNetworkOnline1(Context context) {
    boolean isOnline = false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.getActiveNetwork());  // need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission
        isOnline = capabilities != null && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isOnline;
}
```

Strength: 1. could run on UI thread; 2. fast and accurate.

Weakness: need API >= 23 and compatibility issues.

**Second:**

```
public static boolean isNetworkOnline2() {
    boolean isOnline = false;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = runtime.exec("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int waitFor = p.waitFor();
        isOnline = waitFor == 0;    // only when the waitFor value is zero, the network is online indeed

        // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        // String str;
        // while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //     System.out.println(str);     // you can get the ping detail info from Process.getInputStream()
        // }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isOnline;
}
```

Strength: 1. could run on UI thread; 2. you can ping many times and do statistics for min/avg/max delayed time and packet loss rate.

Weakness: [compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32749462/6482350).

**Third:**

```
public static boolean isNetworkOnline3() {
    boolean isOnline = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); // or your server address
        // URL url = new URL("http://www.baidu.com");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        isOnline = conn.getResponseCode() == 200;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isOnline;
}
```

Strength: could use on all devices and APIs.

Weakness: time-consuming operation, can't run on UI thread.

**Fourth:**

```
public static boolean isNetworkOnline4() {
    boolean isOnline = false;
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 3000);
        // socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("114.114.114.114", 53), 3000);
        isOnline = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isOnline;
}
```

Strength: 1. could use on all devices and APIs; 2. relatively fast and accurate.

Weakness: time-consuming operation, can't run on UI thread.

Comment: 3rd and 4th are strange solutions. What if you have 2G low connection? The result will be "offline" but it's wrong

Answer (score 4):

check with the below set of codes.

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isOnline = false;
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.getActiveNetwork());
                isOnline = capabilities != null && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
            } else {
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                isOnline = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isOnline;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect Solution

Comment: I don't know why but It only works on specific situations not every time

Answer (score 2):

After searching for days and after trying various solutions, some are not perfect some are too LONG, below is a solution suggested by LEVIT using SOCKETS which is PERFECT to me. Any one searching on this solution may consult this post.
[How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Below is the portion of the code with example of task in AsyncTask

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

    private Consumer mConsumer;
    public  interface Consumer { void accept(Boolean internet); }

    public  InternetCheck(Consumer consumer) { mConsumer = consumer; execute(); }

    @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) { try {
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
        sock.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; } }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { mConsumer.accept(internet); }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Usage

    new InternetCheck(internet -> { /* do something with boolean response */ });
```

Below is a summary related to the solution
**Possible Questions**
Is it really fast enough?

*Yes, very fast ;-)*

Is there no reliable way to check internet, other than testing something on the internet?

*Not as far as I know, but let me know, and I will edit my answer.*

What if the DNS is down?

*Google DNS (e.g. 8.8.8.8) is the largest public DNS in the world. As of 2013 it served 130 billion requests a day. Let 's just say, your app would probably not be the talk of the day.*

Which permissions are required?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: If this answer has some technical flaw, please elaborate before voting down because for me, this is working fine and I posted it here so that other people searching on same issue can find the answer here or on given link. Thanks.

Comment: What if I need to check internet for a particular network in a device? Can this solution translate but using a specific Network object?

Comment: Perfectly working

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is just use to check if you are connected to wifi or not. It doesn't check if that wifi is slow or not. (No internet means slow connection).

I tried to use this code. Here, I try to hit google.com and have set a connection timeout value. 
If here internet speed is good, then result returned is 200. So I check if the result code is 200 or not. If not, I show an alert that there is slow internet connection. Use it in an asyntask, and onPostExecute() check the value of returned result.

```
HttpURLConnection urlc = null;
    try {
        urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com")
                .openConnection());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000); // choose your own timeframe
    urlc.setReadTimeout(2000); // choose your own timeframe
    try {
        urlc.connect();

        // returning connection code.
        return (urlc.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it took me the lot of time to check internet connection

Comment: is there any other way to check

Comment: you may try with this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Comment: I also had the same problem, I am following the same code I gave, and it helps me in finding slow internet connection.

There is no method to check if the wifi connection we are connected to is able to ping or not. :)

Answer (score -4):

To just check if you are connected to the internet by Wi-Fi, have a look at the snippet below:

```
NetworkInfo getWifi(){
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    return mWifi;
}
```

Check whether it is connected or not by;

```
if(getWifi().isConnected()) {
//wi-fi connected
}
```

Comment: Kaveesh Kanwal, this is not what he asked for. 
Code snippet you gave is just to check if the device is connected to wifi or not. It doesn't test internet speed.

Comment: The OP has not asked how to check internet speed. Good luck.

Comment: He has also not asked how to check if device is connected to wifi. :)
By no internet access, all we can do is just check packet sending speed on that nw.

Comment: i tried these but i have to check wifi connection and internet connection both

Comment: but the above code return me the only wifi is connected or not

Comment: also in your manifest include: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`