# Ping doesn't work on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, network-programming, ping, samsung-mobile

I wanna use a library from GitHub named "[Android Network Tools](https://github.com/stealthcopter/AndroidNetworkTools)", but actually I have a complex issue when using that. I tested the ping of this library on different type of devices and Android versions, and it worked correctly and was perfect, but when I tested it on my Samsung Galaxy S8 with android 8 I saw pinging external IP(like google.com) didn't work! at the first, I thought it happens in Android 8 and tried to solve it, but I launched it in Android 8 with the emulator that was ok! after that, I decided to test it on my friend's Samsung J7, you can guess that what happened, it didn't work again!
Right now, I'm really really confused because of I don't know why it happens just on Samsung devices, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem, this was about control running apps in the background! when that feature be enabled some methods and ping doesn't work correctly in real-time.

[power saving mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzKXN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code , the problem is occurring because of Device manufacturers They change the Os according to there need which causes issue with ping , see

[Why does ping works on some devices and not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749462/why-does-ping-works-on-some-devices-and-not-others)

Comment: Actually, I had seen this @redman, but I think my problem doesn't relate to that because of the ping of the library worked for 3 or 4 times suddenly like other devices, but unfortunately, I couldn't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. With any power saving mode active, on at least some Android o/s versions, ping will not function. I'm guessing icmp echo reply packets are dropped. A sniffer app would confirm this. It is possible icmp echo (outbound) packets aren't even generated. Crazy in my view. Most ping utilities are very lightweight and I would have thought consume minimal power. I'm running a Samsung J5 / Android v.7.0. Ping started working once I disabled power saving mode