# How to get downlaod and upload speed in android

Tags: android, android-networking

I am working on a backup application. For upload and download I need to check the current internet speed on the device. I am searching if their is any API in android to find out the download and upload speed.
Above API level 21, I found one class `NetworkCapabilities` for this purpose, but how to get it for API below 21.

Comment: Always share what you have tried so far!

Comment: Check similar answer for your question here [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android/8548926#8548926)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection class in https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class can potentially give this information, but you are better off writing your own checker, as the speed depends on too many factors (including the path to the server you are trying to access)