# Android volley doesn't work on local WiFi if 3G/4G is ON

Tags: android, wifi, android-volley, 3g, 4g

I have an app that communicates with a Ricoh Theta camera. The camera creates its WiFi network and OSC (Open Spherical Camera) web server (IP 192.168.1.1, port 80), on which I connect my device. Everything works fine if only the WiFi is ON. But when I also put the mobile data ON, then I get a timeout error.

No sure if it can be useful, but here is some code:

```
protected void executePost(String request, final String body, final RequestListener listener) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://" + mIpAddress + ":" + mPort + request,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if(listener != null) {
                        handleResponse(response, listener);
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if(listener != null) {
                        listener.onError(error);
                    }
                }
            }
    )
    {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

            return body == null ? null : body.getBytes();
        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    stringRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
    mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Is there a way to tell Volley to use the WiFi only? Or first?

Comment: you can check connection type and then allow user to let process further, this link might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/5372087

Comment: Yes thanks for your comment, I found a way to solve the problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

OK, sorry, after some research I found the solution, here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190974

The problem is that as of Android 6.0, if the device is connected to several networks, Android will connect to the one with an internet access, and ignore the other(s). Seems pretty weird, to be polite, but still...

Here is the code I added to make it working:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (Network net : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(net);

        if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(net);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```