# get internet speed (WIFI & Data)

Tags: android, wifi

I am making an App and I need to get the internet speed!I can find the wifi speed with `WifiInfo` clasd but I couldn't find any code or library to get the mobile data speed!
Should I use libraries or there is classes in Android available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to determine the mobile speed precisely, but you can estimate the speed based on the connectivity type (EDGE, HSPA):

```
public static boolean isConnectedFast(final Context context) {
    final NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null) && info.isConnected() && isConnectionFast(info.getType(), info.getSubtype());
}

public static boolean isConnectionFast(final int type, final int subType) {
    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        return true;
    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        switch (subType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
        /*
         * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion
         * to appropriate level to use these
         */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                return false; // ~25 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/6908755 for the full code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Android lib or class that provide this.
**wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed** returns the max speed of the network and it changes from time to time.

Though i found something in FB SDK to get the speed of internet.

```
ConnectionQuality cq = ConnectionClassManager.getInstance().getCurrentBandwidthQuality();
```

here's the github repo:
https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
```

Comment: RSSI determines signal strength and not the network speed.