# how to determine your device is connected to Wi-Fi Direct or Wi-Fi hotspot via Android programming

Tags: android

I want to know that my Mobile device is in Wi-Fi Direct or in hotspot connection programmatically.
Thanks please help me.

Comment: Go through [with this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/8012913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **wifi-direct**

First add permissions in manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.nsdchat"
...

<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
```

...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);

}
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) for more methods and details

For **hotspot**

```
public void getClientList() {
    int macCount = 0;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if (splitted != null ) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];
                System.out.println("Mac : Outside If "+ mac );
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    macCount++;
                   /* ClientList.add("Client(" + macCount + ")");
                    IpAddr.add(splitted[0]);
                    HWAddr.add(splitted[3]);
                    Device.add(splitted[5]);*/
                    System.out.println("Mac : "+ mac + " IP Address : "+splitted[0] );
                    System.out.println("Mac_Count  " + macCount + " MAC_ADDRESS  "+ mac);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mac_Count  " + macCount + "   MAC_ADDRESS  "
                                + mac, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
               /* for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                    System.out.println("Addressssssss     "+ splitted[i]);*/

            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }               
}
```

Comment: @Abdual Kawee : my question is different there are two type of wifi 1. direct and second one is hotspot 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Wi-Fi-Direct-and-Wi-Fi-hotspot-in-mobile
please see difference after you can know more :)

Comment: @PradeepBishnoi wifi direct is another thing

Comment: @PradeepBishnoi I read the link , its exactly what is shared, detection of wifi direct and hotspot, the problem there is no direct method available to differentiate the connectivity you have to make your own logic, above code will help you