# detect if device connect to which network and then send data from server depends on which network connected

Tags: android, networking

I want to check if my android device connected to which network (either wifi, home network, or mobile network) and then I want to use different the url link (use to send data to server) depends on which network the device connected. I'm new to android, and I already googled it but doesn't seems to find the answer or because of my limited vocabulary. Can anybody help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android This post may answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this mate

```
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isConnected()) {
            //do what you want
        } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
            //do what you want
        }
```

and dont forget to put this on your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thank you! I solved the problem, get the wifi ip address and then check if wifi connected with specific ip address and then do other activity.