# How to get mobile network is 4g+ using android programmatically?

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I have a galaxy phone with Airtel SIM card (India) and it is showing I am getting 4G+ network in the notification top window. I want to get the same "4G+" value using android somehow. I tried with TelephonyManager and ConnectivityManager but unable to find any methods that returns "4G+". Any help is really really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding on my Pixel 4A runnging stock A10, the boolean `config_hideLtePlus` isn't available anymore on A10 (and I guess, A11).

However, I've been able to readd support for 4G+ icon in the status bar in a sort of hackish way, i.e. editing systemuigoogle.apk/smali/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/MobileSignalController.smali.

More in-depth, below the line

`iget-boolean v0, v0, Lcom/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/NetworkControllerImpl$Config;->hideLtePlus:Z`

I've replaced

```
if-eqz v0, :cond_4
```

with

```
if-nez v0, :cond_4
```

YMMV

**EDIT 25/8/2021:**

Here is the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/MobileSignalController.java#227

I'm quoting the relevant part:

```
        if (mConfig.show4gForLte) {
        mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE, TelephonyIcons.FOUR_G);
        if (mConfig.hideLtePlus) {
            mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA,
                    TelephonyIcons.FOUR_G);
        } else {
            mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA,
                    TelephonyIcons.FOUR_G_PLUS);
        }
    } else {
        mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE, TelephonyIcons.LTE);
        if (mConfig.hideLtePlus) {
            mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA,
                    TelephonyIcons.LTE);
        } else {
            mNetworkToIconLookup.put(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA,
                    TelephonyIcons.LTE_PLUS);
        }
    }
```

Basically, what I have achieved is triggering the application of lines 7-8, instead of 4-5.

Comment: @saumilsdk: here you are, see my edit above.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

The type is not stored that way, we have standards like 2g, HSDPA, LTE, etc.

```
        switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                return false; // ~25 kbps 
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return false;
         }
```

Please check this answer as it elaborates all the condition scenarios.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/4491971

Comment: Hi @Mohit I had tried this and seems getting LTE for both 4G and 4G+ which is not correct. How does my phone is showing 4G+ in the status then?

Comment: Hi @saumilsdk I saw that in the telephony manager there is no option to identify the 4g+ network. Probably the OEM using a mechanism to identify this network as LTE advanced  or LTE-A or 4g+. You can check this link for more understanding about the generations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_generations and this for more info on LTE-A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_Advanced. I am not sure how we will use the Android SDK to identify the network type. Probably if we check the network speed link support we can come up with a solution. What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking around for a solution as well. Based on my research, it appears that 4G+/LTE+ is not so different from 4G and the plus icon only indicates if it's using carrier aggregation or not.

Due to this, some vendors/carriers do indeed disable this feature in their phones with a special flag called `hideLtePlus` in [Android's code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/c5d02da0f6553a00da6b0d833b67d3bbe87341e0/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/MobileSignalController.java#L252).

Until Android 11's release, there was no way to detect 4G+ on a non-system app (or with some reflections).
Now you can use [TelephonyDisplayInfo.getOverrideNetworkType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyDisplayInfo#getOverrideNetworkType()). If it returns `TelephonyDisplayInfo.OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA` it means you're on 4G+/LTE+.

You can also do something like this (API 26+):

```java
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    ServiceState serviceState = telephony.getServiceState();
    String serviceStateString = serviceState.toString();

    if (serviceStateString.matches("[mI|i]sUsingCarrierAggregation ?= ?true"))
    {
        // You're on 4G+.
    }
}
else
{
    // There's no standard way to detect 4G+ exposed by Android API
}
```

Do note that you'll need both of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions.